# Font won't change in CSS / HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website with PHP and MySQL. I've been activley trying to change the font, but no matter what I do, it won't change. Here is my main CSS file:

```css
header {
    border: 4px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: red;
    background-image: url('marist.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: lightgray;
    font-size:300%;
    padding-top: 15%;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    
}
    
body {
    background-color: salmon
}


#usrform {
    background-color: #CECECE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;    
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

input[type=text],input[type=date] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



textarea {
    width: 150%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    resize: none;
}

select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #CECECE;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #676767;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: none;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}



input[type=button] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: none;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #8B0000;
}
```

Is there something wrong that I'm doing? I've been trying to fix it for a while.
I also have some other CSS files for specific pages of my site, but the font won't change no matter what I do their either.

Comment: Have you `<link>` your **stylesheet** in your **php** file?

Comment: Looking at his css code, their is no need for a `link` as he's using Arial it seems which most machines have pre-installed already.

Comment: @Curious13 I am talking about `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have called the css file at the very bottom of other css files.

Use css like this

```
font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could try in order to solve the problem since you still don't know precisely where the issue is.

- Utilize CSS [!important](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) to force the style to apply.
- [Clear cache](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-clear-your-browser-cache/)